# "Not start with" pattern in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Is there a pattern to match the string not start with a `!`, I searched in Google and SO, seems Lua doesn't have a "not pattern".

```
!xxxx yyyy--match
!はじめまして --match
世界 --not match
test string --not match
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `not` operator as follows:

```
if not str:match "^!" then
    -- what you wanted to do
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The anchor `^` matches the beginning of a string.

To match a string that starts with `!`, use the pattern:

```
"^!"
```

To match a string that doesn't start with `!`, use the pattern:

```
"^[^!]"
```

in which `[^!]` matches any character that isn't `!`.

Comment: This check would fail on empty string